# Python: type ERROR ufunc 'isfinite' when using numpy.ma.masked_invalid()

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am working on a csv file, I would like to do a simple count of unique values using numpy.

```
csv_file = pd.read_csv(file_name)

csv_matrix = csv_file.as_matrix()

unique, counts = np.unique(csv_matrix[:, 15], return_counts=True)
```

however some cells have nan values which prevent me from using `.unique()`:

> TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

I tried to use `np.ma.masked_invalid(csv_matrix)` to solve that problem but now I get the following error:

> TypeError: ufunc 'isfinite' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''

Comment: What's the dtype (and shape)of csvmatrix? Also be careful, a masked array might not work in unique.  You have to use masked aware functions.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for taking the time to help me, I am quite new in both Python and stackoverflow... the data type of csv_matrix is : <class 'numpy.ndarray'> as for the shape it is a two dimensional matrix (36574, 25)

Comment: That's the `type`.  I want to see `csv_matrix.dtype`.  The error suggests it's a mix of objects.  Even if it is `float`, `unique` won't work well.  Floats are close to each other, and rarely exactly equal.

Comment: cells are all string except some that are NaN.

Comment: but when i call csv_matrix.dtype i get "object" and type(csv_matrix.dtype) gets me <class 'numpy.dtype'>. I can use the unique() function when I look at another column of my matrix (where there is no NaN cell), so I really thought that all I had to do was removing the NaN of the column 16

Comment: `pandas` readily creates `object` dtype arrays when it gets mixed values.  The `nan` is a special kind of `float`.  If the other values in the column are strings, the `nan` may be fill for a missing value.  I'd suggest focusing on getting `pandas` to read your file correctly.  I believe `read_csv` has many parameters you can use.  I don't think you understand `numpy` enough to do this after loading.